# text-align:center works in chrome, doesn't work in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, text-align

This is how I use it.

**HTML**

```
<h1>text</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

In **Chrome** everything works good, but aligned to the left in **Safari**. why that happens in Safari?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15286412/4967569

Comment: Add `text-align: -webkit-center;` to your CSS

Answer (score 5):

For Safari

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```