# How to align the last line of the wrapped text without using “text-align-last”

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in which I have set the default alignment for the text to the left, the problem is that I want to show the wrapped text alignment of the last line to the right and I do not want to use the `text-align-last` CSS property as it is not supported in the Safari browser. So is there any way we can do this?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions just because your previous one was closed. Improve the older one by editing.

Comment: Does this answer your question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679627/text-aligncenter-works-in-chrome-doesnt-work-in-safari

Comment: @Addis No, it is text-align-last which is not supported by safari and bug for the same is still unresolved in the bugzilla.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry to say but I didn't find any edits to make because there is no such need to post the code for table structure in which I want to use ```word-break``` whose last line can be aligned but without using ```text-align-last```.