# CSS properties do not show effect in Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have this piece of CSS code that appears on all other browsers that I have tested including Firefox and Chrome but for some reason, they do not appear in the Safari browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  

  input[type=number], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  

  input[type=button] {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: #3a5cd7;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
  }
  

  div {
    padding: 70px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: **It is overridden. This may helps you** https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286412/12247219

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use another version of your code for safari or firefox.

Example for type=number in firefox :

```
input[type=number] {
  
}
```

Example for type=number in safari :

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  
     }
```

I find this here:
[Numeric Inputs – A Comparison of Browser Defaults](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/)

You just have to look for the rest of the inputs